# What do colleges such as Rocky Mountain College of Art and Design look for in a portfolio?

Tags: art, education, portfolio

I really want to get into [Rocky Mountain College of Art and Design (RMCAD)](http://www.rmcad.edu/), but I don't know if my skills are up to par. A representative came down today and she told me the requirements for the [Game Art degree](http://www.rmcad.edu/game-art/overview). Turns out I don't need a portfolio, but I know it would definitely help me out with scholarships, acknowledgement of skill and so on. I want one for myself anyway.

I have a few 'good' sketches and some other 'eh' sketches I don't think are anywhere near my best. I have some life drawings I've been working on as well. To improve my skill I decided to start over and I'm currently learning the human anatomy to draw better skeletons for my characters and such.

I want to be a concept artist with characters and levels/buildings, but... I'm not the best at levels or buildings since I've never really drawn them before. My characters aren't the best, but I am improving. if anyone could help me, I'd greatly appreciate knowing what I should put in my portfolio, how to prepare for college, and etc.

Note: The college is an actual college which is a plus because I can learn my major (game art) plus a minor like business or something else. Maybe architecture...

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not an artist, I think you've mostly answered your own questions:

1. While admissions to the Game Art program can be attained without a portfolio (you'll have to submit a personal statement instead, as noted in [the application checklist](http://www.rmcad.edu/apply-admission/application-checklist)), it may put you at a disadvantage. Applicants are "encouraged" to develop a portfolio prior to submitting an application.
2. Work on and practice what you believe you are weak at -- musculature, anatomy, and drawings of landscapes or buildings, apparently (based on your question).
3. Iterate on your work until you are proud of it. If you're not proud of it, why would you show it off?

It's hard to say exactly what the school (or any school, for that matter) will look for in a portfolio. Some places might want to see only the best work you have to offer, some might want to see a range of your work to show how you have grown and developed on your own. Some may not care if you demonstrate a very narrow focus in terms of media or subject matter, other may consider that a negative and prefer that you show off a broad range of styles, approaches, and subjects.

In the end, you have the most control over making *yourself* happy and satisfied with your portfolio. Focus on that more than what you think other people want to see in you; that alone will make you better, and should help open the doors you want as well.